# How to perform API calls in react native ignite with redux and sagas?

Tags: react-native

I am looking for a demo on how to get it worked. Can any body help me here?

I have read the react-redux and redux-saga on relative articles and help documents. Can you please explain a complete scenario where user clicks on the button and get a response starting from LoginScreen.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate a new Ignite project, there will already be several working API examples you can learn from. This one requests the temperature from a weather API when you click on the various icons, and it goes through Redux (in this case Redux/TemperatureRedux) and the API service (Services/API) to ultimately display a result

- Update:
  To understand how to use redux/saga here is a working login example :
  [Login example with Ignite and redux/saga](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite-example-login/blob/master/App/Containers/LoginScreen.js)